# Chimney masonry recessed at floor. Suggestions?

Tags: trim, masonry

This boiler chimney was constructed with a 3-inch recess where the fieldstone meets the floor. What would be the explanation for this? What would be the correct way to finish (hide or disguise) this? Would any proposed finishes be only for the sides/recesses, or would said proposed finishes continue across the front of the chimney as well (for continuity)? Looking for thoughtful design suggestions.

Also note that the doors to the left side of the chimney (in the second image) have been removed.

[image: Wall with flagstone chimney]

[image: Detail left side of chimney at floor]

[image: Detail base of chimney at floor]

[image: Detail right side of chimney at floor]

Comment: Think it might been done so re-finishing/repairing the floor might be easier.  Floor seems to be cut around a base, the fieldstone finish/face might have been added after.

Comment: What are you actually concerned about?this looks like a clean installation job to me...

Comment: @keshlam, my concern is that I have baseboard meeting a void, and in that void i can see gap filler. The front of the chimney looks clean, I agree. It's the sides that don't see appropriate to me.

Comment: You want some expansion space, normally hidden by the baseboard. Unless you can figure out how to apply (nonflammable) baseboard to stone, or rebuild the fireplace so its stone overlaps the flooring to provide that, I don't see a good fix. But I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: "Looking for thoughtful design suggestions." is explicitly off topic.

Comment: It's the stone on the outside of a chimney, @keshlam, I don't think it needs to be all that nonflammable. If that's getting hot enough to be a fire concern, there are other much more significant issues to deal with than decorating.

Comment: Point granted, @FreeMan.

Answer (score 1):

Neat house, bummer about the the chimney/floor mating. It's never going to look quite right to you now that you know the secret, but it could be better. I would consider 2 options.

1. Fill the side gap with matching stone veneer and mortar. You can cleft or saw stones that would tuck into the void. Might even be just need them an inch or two tall after the mortar, to create the effect that the full width goes through the floor. The downside is still having a non-uniform corner between hardwood and stone, which tends to catch the eye and dirt.
2. (My Pref) Take the base molding around the chimney. You'll have to scribe the trim some, but mostly chisel/grind the stone facade flat to keep the gaps minimal. It actually looks relatively flat already. You probably want to carve/scarf out the rear of the front kick trim. This option gives a nice 90 deg edge from wall to floor, as is customary in well-done houses and in pics of old mansions with custom stone and wood work that I could find online.

Comment: Those do sound plausible to me. I like the base moulding idea -- this is what base moulding is for, after all -- but wonder how much work it's going to be to fit to that irregular surface. You might wind up having to scribe larger pieces to the line, then cut their outer surface to narrow them to consistent thickness...? I'd be interested in seeing the results if this is attempted.